# Can't log into Azure account from Debian 9

Tags: azure, debian, azure-web-app-service, azureportal, debian-stretch

When trying to log into Azure account I get an error saying "You cannot access this right now Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser, app, or location that is restricted by your admin."

It's only on Debian 9, I can log in fine on Ubuntu, Windows 10, and android. Also, it's not a matter of local network because I can log in on Windows 10 and android from the same internet connection. In the details of error everything seems to be okay except I get:

Device identifier: Not Available

Device platform:

Device state: Unregistered

Comment: Can you try to use your personal account (or a different account)  to log in from the same machine.

Comment: It seems more like a restriction/policy at your Tenant level and not something generic with Azure.

Comment: @JasonPan I was able to register and then log into the account using a different email address all from Debian 9. So any ideas why is that? Probably some security settings on this azure account that I can't log into.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I am forced to using windows for now. I am waiting for a response from Azure tech support.

Comment: If you have a solution or answer, you can also post the answer to help more forum users.

Answer (score 0):

According to your personal account test, first of all, we can make it clear that Debian9 supports logging into azure account. Azure does not impose any restrictions on Debian9 devices.

**Steps to troubleshoot:**

1. Are your Debian 9 machine and other Win 10, Ubuntu and other devices in the same domain?
2. Is the Azure account in question given to you by your organization or company?
3. Consult your AAD administrator to understand some policy restrictions.

**Suggestion:**

1. Find your AAD administrator and consult policy restrictions.
2. Find the IT administrator and add the Debian 9 machine to the domain.
3. If the above two suggestions still do not solve the problem, [it is recommended to raise a support ticket for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).